# azure policy to only allow specific tags to be created

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I need to configure an azure policy to make sure that azure contributors create resources using a very specific set of "allowed" tags.
example of allowed tags: application,owner,environment,description,team

if some creates a resource and use the tag "env", the policy will kick in and deny the creation of the resource because "env" is not one of the allowed tags.

Is this possible in azure?

Comment: it depends, when you say "azure contributors" are you referring to the RBAC role or are you referring to any authorized user?  Policy cannot filter based on RBAC.  Otherwise this policy is a pretty straight forward deny policy.

Comment: also it is worth noting that restricting tags may have an undesired effect.  Many resources (like databricks) create tags by default, if you created a policy to deny certain tags, all the default tags in resources will also be held to the same rules.  You could build filtering around these resource types within the policy, but you would have to fix that sort of issue as you run into it.  check out some of the built-in tag compliance policies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies for ideas

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a policy rule that would require all of your listed tags on ALL resources in the assigned scope. (This maybe too much, test it and find out)

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
        "anyOf": [      
            {
                "field": "tags['application']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['owner']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['environment']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['description']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['team']",
                "exists": false
            }
        ]   
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Here is an example that will narrow it down to a resource type. Like VMs only.

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf":[
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        "anyOf": [      
            {
                "field": "tags['application']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['owner']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['environment']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['description']",
                "exists": false
            },
            {
                "field": "tags['team']",
                "exists": false
            }
        ]      
    ]         
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

See my comments attached to the main question. This policy could be too restrictive since some Azure resources have built-in default tags.  Those tags will also be held to this compliance rule, so be careful if you are implementing this on a large organization, you could inadvertently handicap some users.

If you want to narrow it down to a resource group you can do that in your policy assignment, however if you want to do it in your definition you can use the resource type `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups`

Also check out some other tag related policies that come built-in with Azure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies